# How can I send data from a Service to an Activity in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, service

I have a service that is started in Activity1.
Activity1 sends a String which is received by Service1.
When the recent items are closed and Service1's Notification is clicked I want Service1 to open Activity1 using a String from Service1.

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

TIA

TheRealMrP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just Refer this**

**Using Binding/Unbinding of the service**

https://medium.com/@sahityakumarsuman/android-service-communication-with-activity-2c01e537ab03

***OR***

**Using interface trick.**

You can create a interface, define the listener method inside the activity and call the listener method inside your service.
**WARNING**: It can give you null pointer error, so don't forget to check if the service and the activity are alive while calling.

Comment: I thought this was for answering questions ... not voting and criticism ???

Comment: Sorry? what was that for?

Comment: Not you bro ... your assistance was greatly appreciated, I gave u a tick .. I think the other comment was deleted